# Script tag doesn't load all of the time

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have this code but it doesn't load all of the time. Why?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#header").load("/components/navbar.html");
        $("#footer").load("/components/footer.html");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
```

Here's the source code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sargentcoding-official?path=testindex.html%3A45%3A27

Here's the standard page structure:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta title="Sargent Coding" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Sargent Coding" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Sargent Coding" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Where ambition comes to life." />
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      content="https://cdn.glitch.com/5f5ab845-2cb8-4210-b34a-03b1f032163a%2FScratch%20Stuff%20(77)-svg.svg?v=1607718360358"
    />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title id="titleHtml">Sargent Coding</title>
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.com/5f5ab845-2cb8-4210-b34a-03b1f032163a%2F1a81804e-7a4e-4dd6-9c14-43a2bdb9061b_favicon.png?v=1607718475017"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.min.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#header").load("/components/navbar.html");
        $("#footer").load("/components/footer.html");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>

  <!-- Header above. -->
   
  <!-- CODE GOES HERE -->

  <!-- Footer below. -->

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not using jQuery for any reason. I just don't know what I'm doing.

Edit: So, apparently there is a syntax error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-1.10.2.js:612
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.10.2.js:613)
    at text script (jquery-1.10.2.js:8451)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery-1.10.2.js:8426)
    at done (jquery-1.10.2.js:8185)
    at callback (jquery-1.10.2.js:8778)
    at Object.send (jquery-1.10.2.js:8784)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.10.2.js:8136)
    at Function._evalUrl (jquery-1.10.2.js:6718)
```

Comment: Maybe because the function is never told to run or because the script is loaded before the actual site is loaded?

Comment: what you mean with "doesn't load all of the time"? Did you get response errors? Add a Error Handling when `load` is not succeded

Comment: Put your jQuery script at the end of the body not in the head, then it loads after the html, not before. Also why are you loading html pages via jQuery? Seems very inefficient.

Comment: I'm seeing CORS errors on those files you're trying to import.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Because I don't know what I'm doing. I'm bad at HTML.

Comment: You can't import html files this way, better to have some sort of back end system to serve these template html files, WordPress is an example; but just HTML by itself can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found to error, this code is properly working in a local browser (Chrome).

Maybe, you are run this code in the same site: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sargentcoding-official?path=testindex.html%3A45%3A27

site is protected by hidden code and this reason, you have this code but it doesn't load all of the time

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta title="Sargent Coding" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Sargent Coding" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Sargent Coding" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Where ambition comes to life." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.glitch.com/5f5ab845-2cb8-4210-b34a-03b1f032163a%2FScratch%20Stuff%20(77)-svg.svg?v=1607718360358" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title id="titleHtml">Sargent Coding</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn.glitch.com/5f5ab845-2cb8-4210-b34a-03b1f032163a%2F1a81804e-7a4e-4dd6-9c14-43a2bdb9061b_favicon.png?v=1607718475017" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass+Mono" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#header").load("/components/navbar.html");
      $("#footer").load("/components/footer.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>

  <!-- Header above. -->
  <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/5f5ab845-2cb8-4210-b34a-03b1f032163a%2FUntitled%20drawing.svg?v=1611158518090" style="position:absolute; height:17.5em; top: 5.125em; right: 1.5em;" />
  <div>
    <p>&nbsp;<br /><br /></p>
    <h1 class="reallybig">
      <br />
      Where <font color="#4a86e8">ambition</font><br />comes to
      <font color="#21d58e">life</font>.
    </h1>
  </div>
  <a href="/amexpauto.html">
    <div class="frontPageBoxes amexpautoAd"></div>
  </a>
  <br />
  <a href="/amexpauto.html">
    <div class="frontPageBoxes obuioAd"></div>
  </a>

  <!-- Footer below. -->

  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sometimes if you open the page it doesn't load the header at all. It always loads the footer just fine. Just reload the page a lot of times and you'll notice that sometimes it fails.

Comment: Okay, I found something in the console, something about a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with that use of jQuery – where you pass an anonymous function to the first set of brackets. However, if you are trying to invoke an IIFE – [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) – your syntax is slightly off since you do not have the trailing `()`:

This should work:

```js
(function() {
    console.log("Here")
})();
```

Or

```js
(function() {
    console.log("Here")
}());
```

Comment: Where am I supposed to enter this? Also, is there a simpler way of explaining it?

Comment: @Speedblocks Is this a new project or is it one you inherited? If it's a new one that you can do whatever you want with, I highly suggest you don't use jQuery and use something that's more common in modern development stacks. It would take some learning, but you should try React, Vue, or Angular (I'm partial to Angular).

Comment: This project is new, but I grabbed the jQuery code from another StackOverflow article. LOL.